# Linear independence of two functions?

Tags: linear-algebra

1) Let $f, g \in C^{(1)}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ be: 
$$ 
f(t)=e^{t} \operatorname{and} g(t)=e^{-t}
 $$
Show that f and g are linearly independent.

2)$$ 
\begin{array}{l}{\text {Let } h \in C^{(1)}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) \text { be the constant function } h(t)=5, \text { for } t \in \mathbb{R} . \text { Show that } fg \text { and }} \\ {h \text { are linearly dependent. }}\end{array}
 $$
edit: I wrote f,g before. It should be f times g, else they would be linearly independent.

---

1.) In order for f and g to be linearly independent implies: 
$af(t)+bg(t)=ae^t+be^{-t}=0 \implies a=b=0. \; \forall t$

But how do I show this for all t? I know I could set t=0 and t=1, and easily show that those two equations implies a=b=0. But that wouldn't proof it for all t's?

While searching for a solution I learned there are something called a wronskian matrix. But that method isn't in our curriculum, so it should be possible to show without?

---

2)
That f,g,h are linearly dependent could probably be shown in multiple ways.
My approach for this, is showing that h are a linear combination of f and g.

$af(t)+bg(t)=ae^t+be^{-t}=5$ 
If we set b=0, we see: 
$ae^t=5 \implies a=5e^{-t}$

Which shows one example of h being a linear combination of f,g.

But how would you approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a good solution to question 1 worked out, but you're doubting it. To say $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent is to say that, the only values of $a$ and $b$ such that $af + bg$ is the $0$ function, are $a = b = 0$. Equivalently,
$$af(t) + bg(t) = 0 \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R} \implies a = b = 0.$$
Now, if $af(t) + bg(t) = 0$ for any $t$, then it holds for any $t$ you choose to name. You said $t = 0$, and as such
$$af(t) + bg(t) = 0 \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R} \implies af(0) + bg(0) = 0 \implies a + b = 0.$$
The implication definitely holds! The statement $af(t) + bg(t) = 0 \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R}$ entails $af(0) + bg(0) = 0$, and $af(2) + bg(2) = 0$, and $af(-6) + bg(-6) = 0$, and $af(\pi + e) + bg(\pi + e) = 0$, and every other value you wish to substitute in.

Remember, you're attempting to narrow down all the possible values of $a, b \in \Bbb{R}$ to a pair of unique solutions: $a = 0$ and $b = 0$. After you try $t = 0$ and $t = 1$, you find two equations of $a$ and $b$ that you can solve via usual methods, to obtain the unique solution $a = b = 0$. That is, it doesn't even matter how it behaves at other values at $t$, just considering those two values of $t$ will already eliminate all other solutions for $a$ and $b$, thus proving linear independence.

It is possible, prima facie, that the equation
$$af(t) + bg(t) = 0 \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R}$$
has no solutions for $a$ and $b$. Showing that this equation implies $a = b = 0$ only shows that *if* there is a solution (for all $t$), then it must be $a = b = 0$; there may be no solution at all. However, it's quick to see that $a = b = 0$ is indeed a solution (one that works for all $t$), as it always is when finding linear combinations that equal the $0$ vector! Maybe that might help you feel better about this method of proof?

For question $2$, as Jose says, the three functions are linearly independent. Your working shows that
$$5 = (5e^{-t})\cdot e^t + 0 \cdot e^{-t} \quad \forall t \in \Bbb{R}.$$
This is not a linear combination of $e^t$ and $e^{-t}$, as $5e^{-t}$ is not a scalar quantity. It is, in fact, a vector in our space, and the multiplication you're using is a multiplication of vectors (which is likely beyond the scope of your course!). Linear independence relies on the coefficients being scalars!

Instead, try the same method as above, now with three different values for $t$.

Comment: Okay thank you very much.
I do see that I $a=5e^{-t}$ is not a scalar.

But I'm not quite sure why, solving the system of equations in question a) with t=0 and t=1, shows that a=b=0 for all t. Doesn't that only show that f,g are linearly independent for t=0 and t=1?

Comment: There's no such thing as $f$ and $g$ being linearly independent for $t = 0$ and $t = 1$. To be linearly independent, it means that, if a linear combination of $f$ and $g$ comes to be the $0$ vector (i.e. the function that is $0$ everywhere), then the coefficients must be $0$ (scalars). In order to have $af + bg = 0$ as vectors, you need them to be equal as functions, not just at specific points. Since you are assuming $af + bg = 0$, you are assuming $af(t) + bg(t) = 0$ **for all** $t$, not just $t = 0$ and $t = 1$. It's a big (but justified) assumption!

Comment: You obviously don't need to use all of this assumption. You don't need more than two values of $t$. You're assuming it holds for all $t$, but as soon as you know $af(t) + bg(t) = 0$ for two different values of $t$, then you know the values of $a$ and $b$: $0$. You took the assumption, whittled it away to sufficient information to get the conclusion you wanted, and consequently got a valid proof. That's mathematics!

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider the assertion $(\forall t\in\mathbb R):ae^t+be^{-t}=0$. Then, in particular, $a+b=0$ (just take $t=0$) and $ae+\frac be=0$ (just take $t=1$). But it follows from these two equalities that $a=b=0$. So, $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent.
2. You can't prove that, since $f$, $g$, and $h$ are linearly *independent*. Just use the same method as above.

Answer (score 1):

Is it not much simpler to show this using test values of t.
For example, one can prove the linear independence of sin and cos by simply considering the following:
$$acos(x)+bsin(x)=0$$
$$taking \ x=\pi/2 \   \implies\   \ b=0 $$ while taking $$x=0 \   \implies\   \ a=0$$

Similarly for the above we can take values of t as follows:
$$t=0 \implies\ a+b=0 \implies\ b=-a$$
\
$$t=1 \implies\ ae+be^{-1}=ae-ae^{-1}=a(e-e^{-1})=0 \implies\ a=0 \implies\ b=0$$

We are able to do this, as our fixed values of a and b must hold for all t to satisfy the equation, including our chosen random test points.

Another more clever way to do this is find an inner product on the function space, and show the two functions are perpendicular. This then implies that they must be linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $$t=1$$ into your equation we get
$$ae+be^{-1}=0$$ and for $$t=0$$ : $$a+b=0$$ so you will get two equations for solving.

Comment: Ok, then it is clear to me.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. But why does that imply that it's true for all t? Doesn't that only proof it for t=0 and t=1?

Comment: It should be true for ALL $t$ and when you find some $t$ for which this statement is not true, then your statement is not true.

Answer (score 0):

> But how do I show this for all t? I know I could set t=0 and t=1, and
>   easily show that those two equations implies a=b=0. But that wouldn't
>   proof it for all t's?

Actually, the claim you must prove is this:

$$(\forall t: a\cdot e^t + b\cdot e^{-t} = 0)\implies (a=b=0)$$

There is nothing about "for all $t$" on the right hand side of this statement. Therefore, it is perfectly valid to only take $t=0,1$ and use that to prove that $a=b=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall from linear algebra that two vectors v and w are called linearly dependent if there are nonzero constants c1 and c2 with.

```
    c1v + c2w  =  0
```

We can think of differentiable functions f(t) and g(t) as being vectors in the vector space of differentiable functions.  The analogous definition is

```
    Let f(t) and g(t) be differentiable functions.  Then they are called linearly dependent if there are nonzero constants c1 and c2 with 

    c1f(t) + c2g(t)  =  0
```

for all t.  Otherwise they are called linearly independent.

Example

The functions f(t)  =  2sin2 t  and  g(t)  =  1 - cos2(t) are linearly dependent since

```
    (1)(2sin2 t) + (-2)(1 - cos2(t))  =  0
```

Example

The functions f(t) = t and g(t)  =  t2 are linearly independent since otherwise there would be nonzero constants c1 and c2 such that

```
    c1t + c2t2  =  0
```

for all t.  First let t  =  1.  Then

```
    c1 + c2  =  0
```

Now let t  =  2.  Then

```
    2c1 + 4c2  =  0
```

This is a system of 2 equations and two unknowns.  The determinant of the corresponding matrix is

```
    4 - 2  =  2
```

Since the determinant is nonzero, the only solution is the trivial solution.  That is

```
    c1  =  c2  =  0
```

The two functions are linearly independent.

In the above example, we arbitrarily selected two values for t.  It turns out that there is a systematic way to check for linear dependence.  The following theorem states this way.

Theorem

Let f and g be differentiable on [a,b].  If Wronskian W(f,g)(t0)  is nonzero for some t0 in [a,b] then f and g are linearly independent on [a,b].  If f and g are linearly dependent then the Wronskian is zero for all t in [a,b].

Example

Show that the functions f(t)  =  t   and g(t)  =  e2t are linearly independent.

Solution

We compute the Wronskian.

```
    f '(t)  =  1        g '(t)  =  2e2t
```

The Wronskian is

```
    (t)(2e2t) - (e2t)(1)
```

Now plug in 0 to get

```
    W(f,g)(0)  =  -1
```

which is nonzero.  We can conclude that f and g are linearly independent.

Proof

If

```
    c1f(t) + c2g(t)  =  0
```

Then we can take derivatives of both sides to get

```
    c1f '(t) + c2g '(t)  =  0
```

This is a system of two equations with two unknowns.  The determinant of the corresponding matrix is the Wronskian.  Hence, if the Wronskian is nonzero at some t0, only the trivial solution exists.  Hence they are linearly independent.

There is a fascinating relationship between second order linear differential equations and the Wronskian.  This relationship is stated below.

Abel's Theorem

Let y1 and y2 be solutions on the differential equation

```
      L(y)  =  y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y  =  0
```

where p and q are continuous on [a,b].  Then the Wronskian is given by

where c is a constant depending on only y1 and y2, but not on t.  The Wronskian is either zero for all t in [a,b] or no t in [a,b].

Proof

First the Wronskian

```
     W  =  y1y2' - y1'y2
```

has derivative

```
    W'  =  y1'y2' + y1y2'' - y1''y2 - y1'y2'  =   y1y2'' - y1''y2
```

Since y1 and y2 are solutions to the differential equation, we have

```
    y1'' + p(t)y1' + q(t)y1  =  0

    y2'' + p(t)y2' + q(t)y2  =  0
```

Multiplying the first equation by -y2 and the second by y1 and adding gives

```
     (y1y2'' - y1''y2) + p(t)(y1y2' - y1'y2)  =  0
```

This can be written as

```
    W' + p(t)W  =  0
```

This is a separable differential equation with

```
    dW/W  =  -p(t)dt
```

Now integrate and Abel's theorem appears.

Example

Find the Wronskian (up to a constant) of the differential equations

```
    y'' + cos(t) y  =  0
```

Solution

We just use Abel's theorem, the integral of cos t is sin t hence the Wronskian is

```
    W(t)  =  cesin t
```

A corollary of Abel's theorem is the following

Corollary

Let y1 and y2 be solutions to the differential equation

```
    L(y)  =  y'' + p(t)y' + q(t)y  =  0
```

Then either W(y1,y2) is zero for all t or never zero.

Example

Prove that

```
    y1(t)  =  1 - t     and     y2(t)  =  t3
```

cannot both be solutions to a differential equation

```
    y'' + p(t)y + q(t)  =  0
```

for p(t) and q(t) continuous on [-1,5].

Solution

We compute the Wronskian

```
    y1'  =  -1        y2'  =  3t2

    W(y1,y2)  =  (1 - t)(3t2) - (t3)(-1)  =  3t2 - 2t3
```

Notice that the Wronskian is zero at t  =  0 but nonzero at t  =  1.  By the above corollary, y1 and y2 cannot both be solutions.